# How to read and display an input in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. I want to display a simple input but it does not work. Here is my code

```
    x = raw_input("What is your name?  ")
    print "Hello  ".x
```

And My result is:

```
    What is your name?  Nhan
```

It does not display the result.

Comment: Please read up on [input and output in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: String concatenation in Python uses `+`, not `.` (like PHP for instance)

Comment: You should get a syntax error.

Comment: `print "Hello  {}".format(x)`    https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: it seems that it does not relate to syntax error although i changed to "," or "+".

Answer (score -1):

Use a comma instead of a dot or a `+` sign in concatenating strings.

```
x = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "Hello", x
```

or

```
print "Hello " + x
```

NOTE: A comma automatically adds space in string concatination, while `+` do not. So you can get rid of the space after the "Hello" when using a comma.

Comment: it seems that it does not relate to syntax error although i changed to "," or "+". It does not terminate the program

Comment: a comma does not concatenate strings. [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) takes multiple inputs separated with comma. That is different. try `x = "a", "b"` It won't concatenate.

Answer (score -1):

for 3.0 version and above:

```
    x = input("Hello what is your name?")
    print("Hello",x)
```

below 3.0 versions:

```
    x = raw_input("Hello what is your name?")
    print("Hello %s")%x
```

note: if you had multiple inputs and they were in the same sentence do this

```
    print("some example %s and another %s and another %s")%(a, b, c)
```